# How to detect swiping (and execute an action upon it) with an iOS14 TabView's PageTabViewStyle() page-swipe?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview, pagetabviewstyle

Using Swift5.3.2, iOS14.4.2, XCode12.4,

I am struggling with this new iOS14 feature for creating PageViews in SwiftUI.

It all works, except I cannot detect the moments of swipe !

I tried using `.onChange(selectionIndex)` but as soon as I create this change-listener to the TabView's `selectionIndex`, the swipe stalls. It is no longer smooth.

```
struct MyView: View {

    @State var selectionIndex = 0

    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection: $selectionIndex) {
            ForEach(mediaList.paths.indices, id: \.self) { index in
               SomePageView(media: mediaList.paths[index])
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        .onChange(of: selectionIndex) { newIdx in
            
            customDotsService.selectedIndex = newIdx  // because TabView's PageViewStyle does not have little dots that can be placed somewhere else on screen...
            sendCommand(index: newIdx) // some background task to send commands to other services...
        }
    }
}
```

Even if my `onChange(selectionIndex) { newIdx in ... }` remains completely empty, the swipe stalls and memory goes to the loops.

It is really an annoying problem and I am on it since 4 days non-stop.

Any help highly appreciated.

What I need from Apple: a working PageView that has correct life-cycle methods `.onAppear()`, `.onChange(selectionIndex)` and its little-Dots-Indicator that can be placed anywhere on screen. Help universe, help that we get this in SwiftUI.

Comment: TabView is not 100% ready to use has lots of issue, so having this kind of issue is understandable

Comment: ähm and since when does Apple release `not 100% ready` API's ??? And when will it be ready ?  I am paying 100 bucks for having the privilege to be an Apple developer - will I get those reimbursed soon ? I appreciate the new SwiftUI and I can see its complexity. But shouldn't Apple only release `100 % ready` Software API's ? (...sorry - the 4 days of agony hit me right now... - it is obviously not your fault).

Comment: I say what apple doing right now, apple gave some thing to work like TabView, but most important apple gave possibility to make our own Custom TabView, which is important for me. if apple wants make everything 100% ready for us, then Xcode would be Numbers app or Excel. even Binding has issue right now! or StateObject so basic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this solution and it works as expected. Need to add tag value to `View` which is used in `ForEach`, then call `onChange` block and you'll able to detect swiping there.

```
struct OnboardingPagerView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = OnboardingPagerViewModel()
    @State private var selectedPageIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedPageIndex) {
                ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    TitleWithDescriptionView(title: item.title, description: item.description)
                        .tag(item.index)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedPageIndex) { newValue in
                debugPrint("[a]: new value \(newValue)")
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander, I will definitively have a look at this.